# TOR won't load because no permission

Tags: connection

Tor worked just fine for years then it now gives this message:

> Tor browser does not have permission to access the profile.
> Please adjust your file system permissions and try again.

Comment: Seems like a permission problem. Delete Tor browser and install it in your desktop folder, see if that helps.

Comment: The same problem was also faced by me today .
Just open Tor Browser with "Run as Administration" then it will work fine.
also you can install tor browser in different location instead of local disk C.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Had the same problem once. The issue is an user called "debian-tor" on Linux should own /var/lib/Tor and /etc/tor

You have to use chown as sudo

```
sudo chown -R debian-tor /var/lib/tor
sudo chown -R debian-tor /etc/tor
```

On windows, I believe the best solution is to check the permission of the folder Tor is in - allow all for everybody

Answer (score 0):

For GNU/Linux, if you've installed Tor manually, make sure you own the installation files. Supposing you extracted Tor into `/opt`, you should run (replace en-US with the language you downloaded) :

```
sudo chown -R `whoami` /opt/tor-browser_en-US
```

Comment: Is that not possible the same tor installation for different users?